# Accessing frames via the DOM in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

OK, every other browser works fine with the method I have coded so far but for some reason Internet Explorer will not work. I have spent hours of time (more time than actually developing the feature!) on compatibility and am close to giving up!

I have a forum and one of its neat features is the WYSIWYG editor. For that, I essentially have an IFrame that acts as the document:

```
<iframe name="writer" src="/scripts/blank.html" class="writer"></iframe>
```

This is the current state of the JavaScript (constantly updated):

```
function initEditor()
{
    w = frames['writer']
    wc = g('writerCopy')

    if(w == null) return

    frames['writer'].document.designMode = 'on'
    frames['writer'].document.body.innerHTML = styleSheet+wc.value
    frames['writer'].focus()
}
```

It works partially now, but fails on the line:

```
frames['writer'].document.body.innerHTML = styleSheet+wc.value
```

in Internet Explorer with "'frames.writer.document.body' is null or not an object".

Comment: Are you getting a JavaScript or IE error when you do this, or just it just not work?

Comment: I get a meaningless JavaScript error. I'll add it to the post in one minute.

Comment: You could clarify your question by adding some info as to what you have done and what is your debugging setup, so as to avoid redundant questions. You also assume that the answer must involve the try-block, but leave that to the answerers or clarify why.

Comment: I am open to other methods (that's just a suggestion).

Comment: Did you name your frame? otherwise "writer" would be undefined. And once again, hace you checked that IE supports designMode? I believe not.

Comment: IE seems to support it... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753622(VS.85).aspx

Comment: This is a terrible title. Who fixes titles around here? Maybe "accessing frames via the DOM in IE" or similar?

Comment: Good suggestion Ambrose.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the poor title. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used frames['frameName'].document.write('someText') but only if the other method fails.

Answer (score 1):

Have you activated IE's [debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bg182326(v=vs.85)) [facilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even sure IE supports that designMode.

And, .contentDocument is only IE8, IE7 and less uses .contentWindow.document, but iframe windows are part of the frames-collection.

try this, should be crossbrowser:

```
<iframe name="writer"></iframe>

frames["writer"].document.body.innerHTML = "some html...";
```

Comment: Changed, it works far better now - thanks! But it still fails (as noted above).

Answer (score 1):

You need to point your iframe to a dummy document for IE. Just create a file `blank.html` with the following:

```
<html><body></body></html>
```

and set `<iframe src="blank.html" ... >`

Then you can go about referencing `frame.document.body.innerHTML = '...'` to your hearts content.

BTW that is a terrible title to a question.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it still gives the same error. I checked manually that the /blank.html page loads as it should and included the exact code above.

Comment: It'd be easier to just use <iframe src="about:blank" ...> -- there's no need to create another file when the browser is perfectly capable of generating a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently IE8 does not make frame elements available until the entire parent page has loaded.  Also note, you can write to the frame before the parent page loads, but this will overwrite the frame and prevent it from being loaded.

The easy solution is to move the InitEditor() call from inside the body to here:

```
<body onload="InitEditor()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the iframe isn't loaded yet. I can duplicate your "'frames.writer.document.body' is null or not an object" error. I added a setTimeout around it and it then worked for me.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    frames['writer'].document.body.innerHTML = "some text";
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here? shouldn't you use something like:

```
window.frames[nameOrNumberOfFrame]...
```

See also in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537459(VS.85).aspx):

> This collection contains only window
>   objects and does not provide access to
>   the corresponding frame and iframe
>   objects. To access these objects, use
>   the **all** collection for the document
>   containing the objects.

Comment: I am using window.frames now. Are you suggesting I should use the <i>all</i> collection instead?

Comment: I am suggesting you use what ever Microsoft declares you should use - its their browser after all...